# Lombok Data annotation 'The constructor is undefined'

Tags: java, lombok

I am using Lombok in a spring boot project with Maven. My IDE is vscode

I tried using Lombok annotators to create a class like so:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooModel {
    private String name;
}
```

And it worked fine. However, when I tried to switch to the `@Data` annotation instead, I got an error:

```
@Data
public class FooModel {
    private String name;
}
```

```
The constructor FooModel(String) is undefined
```

I thought the @Data annotation was supposed to build the constructor for me. What's going on here?

Comment: Did you triy maven clean before running it again? Usually this fixes problems for me when using lombok

Comment: Yes, still get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data):

> `@Data` is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter` / `@Setter` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` together.

Because your `name` field isn't `final`, it isn't a "required arg". Either make it `final` so that `@RequiredArgsConstructor` takes it into account, or keep your `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation alongside `@Data`.