# hibernate "No default constructor for entity" created with @Data annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, lombok

I am trying to set up a database table using a JpaRepository. I have the following model class:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class MyModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String imagePath;
}
```

When I run my application the table is created just fine. I have manually added a row to the table, yet when I try to look up the row using `repository.findById` I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.mypackage.mypackage.model.MyModel
```

I am confused by the 'no default constructor' error. I thought the `@Data` annotation automatically created a constructor for the class?

Comment: @sp00m's comment is correct. But as an explanation ... "[`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter` / `@Setter` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` together". So, there is no `@NoArgsConstructor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernates doesn't play with with immutable entities, it wants:

- a nullary constructor: `public MyModel() {}`
- getters and setters

So just remove the `final` modifiers so that `@Data` generates all this for you.

---

Ah, that's why it rings a bell, it relates to that other [question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73126632/1225328). So yeah, with Hibernate entities, you can't easily use immutable entities. You can still add `@AllArgsConstructor` alongside `@Data` if you need such a constructor too.

---

**Edit:** As rightfully raised by [Andrey B. Panfilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov) in the comments, `@Data` shouldn't be used at all on top of entities. Quoting [Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/):

> The bottom line is that you can use the `@Getter`, `@Setter`, and `@Builder` annotation without breaking your application. The only Lombok annotations you need to avoid are `@Data`, `@ToString`, and `@EqualsAndHashCode`.

Comment: `Hibernates doesn't play with with immutable entities` - and with `@EqualsAndHashCode` it does not play well :) and `@ToString` may raise exceptions in case of lazy proxies. The valid set of lombok annotations for JPA entities is: `@Getter`, `@Setter` and `@NoArgsConstructor`